# Read and Write data from/to BLOB in MS SQL using Visual C++ and OLE DB

Tags: sql-server, visual-c++, oledb, blob, read-write

ca you help me? I am looking for example how to insert and get data from BLOB in MS SQL Server 2008.
I am using OLE DB and Visual C++.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's detailed info on that topic (the write side anyway) here: [Sending BLOB Data to SQL SERVER Using IROWSETFASTLOAD and ISEQUENTIALSTREAM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sqlnativeclient/sending-blob-data-to-sql-server-using-irowsetfastload-and-isequentialstream).

> Most of the available samples are too
> simplistic and don’t demonstrate
> varying data length per row or using
> ISequentialStream. In this sample,
> you'll see both techniques in one
> source file.  By default, the sample
> shows how to use IRowsetFastLoad to
> send variable length BLOB data per row
> using in-line bindings.  In this case,
> the in-line BLOB data must fit in
> available memory.  This method has
> better performance when the BLOB data
> is a few bytes to a few MB, because
> there is no additional stream
> overhead.  For larger data, especially
> where the data is not necessarily all
> available at once in a block,
> streaming is a better choice.

For readback there is background and sample code on MSDN [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/native-client-ole-db-blobs/getting-large-data?view=sql-server-ver15).

> The SQL Server Native Client OLE DB
> provider does not retrieve large data
> from SQL Server until requested to do
> so by the consumer. The consumer
> should bind all short data in one
> accessor, and then use one or more
> temporary accessors to retrieve large
> data values as required.

Comment: the article is really unreadable. it is formated terribly.. but i cant find no other example

Comment: If you cut and paste the code into VS it's easy to select and format it to improve readability.  I agree it's not well laid out but the design advice (for write at least) is excellent.

Comment: I have found example project here:
http://msftdpprodsamples.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=SS2008!README%20How%20to%20set%20large%20data%20(OLE%20DB)